# Unable to display dataframe records using spark scala for CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I have created `dataframe` by converting `RDD` to `DF` using map function. When I try to display records it is giving me `exception`.
Below is my code:

```
//Created case class
case class employees(emp_id:java.lang.Long,emp_name:String, job_name:String,manager_id:java.lang.Long,hire_date:String,salary:java.lang.Double,commision:java.lang.Double,dep_id:java.lang.Long);

// Created DF
val employeesDf=rd1.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>employees(p(0).toLong,p(1),p(2),p(3).toLong,p(4),p(5).toDouble,p(6).toDouble,p(7).toLong)).toDF()

//Schema    
scala> employeesDf
    res5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp_id: bigint, emp_name: string, job_name: string, manager_id: bigint, hire_date: string, salary: double, commision: double, dep_id: bigint]
```

But when I try to show some records it throws an exception. Below is the `error`:

```
scala> employeesDf.show()
18/08/05 07:08:43 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Below is the dataset for employees:

[DATASET IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dexr.jpg)

So where am I going wrong ?? I am stuck since hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by creating UDF's and using it in map function. Below are the codes:

```
//Create case class for schema :

case class employees(emp_id:java.lang.Long,emp_name:String, job_name:String,manager_id:java.lang.Long,hire_date:String,salary:java.lang.Double,commision:java.lang.Double,dep_id:java.lang.Long);

// Create UDF’s for Long and double :

def getDoubleValue(value:String):Double= {
  val output:Double=if (value != null && value.trim.length>0) {
    value.toDouble
  }else{
    0D
  }
  output
}
def getLongValue(value:String):Long= {
  val output:Long=if (value != null && value.trim.length>0) {
    value.toLong
  }else{
    0L
  }
  output
}

// Create RDD

val rdd=sc.textFile("file:////home/hduser/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter(p=>{p!=null && p.trim.length>0})


// Create DF

val df=rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>employees(getLongValue(p(0)),p(1),p(2),getLongValue(p(3)),p(4),getDoubleValue(p(5)),getDoubleValue(p(6)),getLongValue(p(7)))).toDF()

// Display records:

df.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataframe's` some of the column contains `empty strings` and you are trying to `parsing` them to `double` , `long`. So either change these `column` to `strings` in case class or use `if-else` condition in parsing based on your business requirements. Like below

```
//Sample data in test.txt

65646,JONAS,MANAGER,68319,1991-04-02,2957.00,,2001
64989,ADELYN,SALESMAN,66928,1991-02-20,1700.00,400.00,3001

val rdd=sc.textFile("C:\\spark\\programs\\test.txt").filter(p=>{p!=null && p.trim.length>0})

// Created DF
rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>employees(p(0).toLong,p(1),p(2),if(p(3).length>0) p(3).toLong else 0,p(4),if(p(5).length>0) p(5).toDouble else 0, if(p(6).length>0) p(6).toDouble else 0,p(7).toLong)).toDF().show

//Output: 

+------+--------+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------+
|emp_id|emp_name|job_name|manager_id| hire_date|salary|commision|dep_id|
+------+--------+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------+
| 65646|   JONAS| MANAGER|     68319|1991-04-02|2957.0|      0.0|  2001|
| 64989|  ADELYN|SALESMAN|     66928|1991-02-20|1700.0|    400.0|  2001|
+------+--------+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------+
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "400.00"

Comment: Use trim also like p(6).trim.toDouble

Comment: Tried. Doesn't help

Comment: @Debuggerr Please see my latest answer and its working fine

Comment: No bro i even tried in spark 2.2.1..still it gives me the error ...in which environment did you try ?? are you using spark1.6 version and cdh cluster ?? but even in spark 2.0 version i am facing this issue

Comment: Thank you @Manoj for helping me but i resolved it ..I have posted my answer

Comment: Even your code is also correct but need to write filter(p=>{p!=null && p.trim.length>0}) at the end while creating RDD.